How can we add new sections to appsettings after build?
I'm working on a WPF C# program that we want to customize based on its location. I'm using DI with IOptions and I've read through dozens of options for adding particular variations of configBuilder.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{some_variation}.json"). My particular situation requires me to load a specific json file based on a setting in the main appsettings.json file. I can't get to it until after configBuilder.build(), can I? Can I add more sections after configBuilder.Build() runs?
    IConfigurationBuilder configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

    if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT") != null
        && Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT").Length > 0)
        configBuilder.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT")}.json");

So far, so good. But now I need settings that are specific to the site where it's used. In the main settings I have this
"Plant": {
    "Site": "0201",
    "Abbrev": "SAC"
}

and I'd like to add a new file appsettings.plc.SAC.json. I can't access the AppSettings.Plant.Abbrev until after configBuilder.Build() runs and I can't use AddJsonFile after that's done.
On site it could use the Environment.MachineName.Substring(0,3), but that won't work during development. Maybe I should put the site info into launch options. I'm not sure if that's the best idea. Anyone have any other solutions?
TIA, Mike

You could use another builder to parse the value before you actually configure your app:
var abbrev = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .Build().GetSection("Plant")["Abbrev"];

IConfigurationBuilder configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
...

Or parse the file yourself somehow else. After all, it's just a text based configuration file.
